# Textfield Quiz "Where to enter the answer yourself "

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to make a quiz app where you can enter the answer using the keyboard. I've tried many things now, but none of my solutions helped me. Can anyone help me?

```
 Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new TextField(
                     decoration: InputDecoration(labelText:"put in the correct answer", 
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                      ),
                      key: _formKey,
                      autovalidate: true,
                      validator: (String value){
                        if (value.contains("test") ){
                        return "pleas more";
                        }else{
                        return null;}
                      }
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                            debugPrint("The Answer is correct.");
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                  ),

              ],)
            ]
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Form`, `GlobalKey` and `TextFormField` instead of normal `TextField` to validate the results.

```
// create a GlobalKey 
GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
         Form( // create a form
           key: _formKey, // assign key
           child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Your answer", labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              autovalidate: true,
              validator: (String value) {
                if (value.contains("test")) {
                  return "pleas more";
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
              }),
         ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Validate"),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                debugPrint("The Answer is correct.");
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make your code so complicated if you just have one `TextField`.

Just declare a variable to store a `TextEditingController` as a class variable(anywhere inside your class outside of any code block) to store `TextEditingController`  and pass it to the `controller` parameter of your `TextField`.

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
```

Simplified Solution Code:

```
Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new TextField(
                     decoration: InputDecoration(labelText:"put in the correct answer", 
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                      ),
                      controller: _controller,
                  onSubmitted: (answer) {
                      if (answer.contains("test")) debugPrint("The answer is correct");}
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: (){
             if (_controller.text.contains("test")) debugPrint("The answer is correct");}
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                  ),

              ],)
            ]
    )
```